# Bessel functions: Negative integer order

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, special-functions, bessel-functions

I would like to show that for the Bessel functions, we have:

$J_{-m}(x) = (-1)^m J_m(x)$.

This can be obtained by using the definition of the Bessel functions as

$J_m(x) = \big(\frac{x}{2}\big)^m \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k! (k + m)!} \big(\frac{x}{2}\big)^{2k}$.

Now, I have come across the integral representation of the Bessel functions which reads

$J_m(x) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\pi d\theta \cos(x \sin\theta - m \theta)$.

Is it possible to obtain the negative integer order feature of the Bessel functions from this integral?

**Edit**

This problem can be solved by a change of variable $\theta = \pi - t$ in the expression for $J_{-m}(x)$.

Comment: What did you try?  In this forum, you are supposed to show your efforts, not merely ask us to do it for you.

Comment: Hint: Change variables $t = \pi-\theta$.

Comment: @GEdgar Many thanks! It worked! Two days, I was struggling with this!